# How to split values/text from two column format with reference to a column into multiple columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Here is the data:

| Old Material Number | New Material Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 110 |
| 1 | 120 |
| 1 | 130 |
| 2 | 210 |
| 2 | 220 |
| 3 | 310 |

Desired Output

| Old Material Number | New Material Number 1 | New Material Number 2 | New Material Number 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 110 | 120 | 130 |
| 2 | 210 | 220 |  |
| 3 | 310 |  |  |

I tried using Group By function in the Power query but was unable to create additional columns to transform the data. Please guide on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate method that is not hard coding number of columns

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Old Material Number"}, {{"data", each Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"New Material Number", "Index"}, {"New Material Number", "Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US")[Index]), "Index", "New Material Number")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this solution, but it is resulting in an error:
Expression.Error: 5 arguments were passed to function which expects between 2 and 4.
Details:
    Pattern=
    Arguments=List


However, after pasting this query into the advanced editor it shows that no syntax errors are there...

Comment: Sorry, not sure what is happening on your end. With your sample code this works perfectly

Comment: I couldn't fix it. It is still showing the same error even if I created a new file.

Answer (score 1):

This task can be accomplished quite easily using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> as well, which will be the **`easiest approach`**. Available in <kbd>Windows</kbd> **`Excel 2010+`** and **`Excel 365`** <kbd>Windows or Mac</kbd>

---

[image]

---

- First convert the source range into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"New Material Number", type text}}),

    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Old Material Number"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Old Material Number=number, New Material Number=nullable text]}}),

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All.1", each Table.AddIndexColumn([All],"Index",1,1)),

    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom",{"All.1"}),

    #"Expanded All.1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "All.1", {"Old Material Number", "New Material Number", "Index"}, {"Old Material Number", "New Material Number", "Index"}),

    #"Added Prefix" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded All.1", {{"Index", each "New Material Number" & Text.From(_, "en-US"), type text}}),

    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Prefix", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Prefix", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US")[Index]), "Index", "New Material Number")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Also since you have tagged **`Excel-Formulas`**, then you can do the following using <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper function <kbd>MAKEARRAY( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α,A2:A7,
     σ,COUNTIF(α,α),
     ß,MAX(σ),
     Ω,ROWS(α),
     VSTACK(HSTACK($A$1,$B$1&" "&SEQUENCE(1,ß)),
     IFERROR(UNIQUE(HSTACK(α,MAKEARRAY(Ω,ß,
     LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(FILTER(B2:B7,α=INDEX(α,r)),c))))),"")))
```

---

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked indeed. 
Is this can be achieved by code only? Is it possible to do the same in the power query interface?

Comment: @NickG7 Yes I have posted both `Formulas` as well as `Power Query`, kindly check

Comment: This is hardcoding: {"New Material Number.1", "New Material Number.2", "New Material Number.3"}

Comment: #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Grouped Rows", {{"New Material Number", type text}}, "en-US"), "New Material Number", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv),List.Transform({1 .. List.Max(Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "count", each List.Count(Text.PositionOfAny([New Material Number],{","},Occurrence.All))+1)[count])}, each "New Material Number." & Text.From(_)))

Comment: What made your initial response interesting was the Text.Combine() and then split. Sorry to see you removed that.

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest solution to handle this problem through power query pivot table feature .